# Xcode 4, debugging, breakpoints, NSLogs

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I am hoping someone can help me.  I have just started running xcode 4.01 and for some reason whenever I run an app, it does not stop on breakpoints or display the NSlog messages.  I have a message in my viewDidLoad and it never shows.  I even breakpoint on this log and the best I can get in the output window is:

pending breakpoint 1 - "universalTestAppDelegate_iPad.m:15" resolved

pending breakpoint 2 - "universalTestAppDelegate_iPhone.m:16" resolved

Actual code is:

```
-(void) viewDidload
{
   NSLog("in viewDidLoad");  
}
```

So it appears it sees the breakpoint but never stops on it.  As I said, brand new to xcode 4 so any idea on what I am doing wrong?  Uninstalled and reinstalled and still nothing.  Also, if it means anything, in the Scheme to choose where to run, I can select IOS devie, iPad 43 simulator and iPhone 4.3 simulator.  Tried both and still nothing.  Why can't I select/see other versions of the IOS?

BTW:  The above is because I do not have my iPad or iPhone connected.  Thanks in advance for any and all help.

Geo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two possibilities:

1. You don't have breakpoints turned on. Use the Product->Debug->Activate Breakpoints command to rectify this.
2. You have breakpoints turned on but you placed your breakpoints on lines that haven't been executed. If your log statement doesn't appear in the console, that would indicate that the method containing that statement isn't executing, so it's no surprise that the breakpoint on that line has no effect.

Comment: Checked all of this and still no output or stopping at breakpoints.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on main(). If you hit that, you know that the problem is that the code with your breakpoint isn't executing (which we already suspect is the case since there's no log output either).

Comment: For what its worth, this was a straight out of the box for a Universal app  I added the viewDidLoad to each class (iPhone / iPad).  Doesn't the viewDidLoad always get hit after the view loaded?

Comment: Only if the class is a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Okay.  So before I get flamed, let em get this straight.  The "shell" universal project creates an univeral_appDeligate and a iphoneAppdelgate plus iPadAppdelegate.  Each with their own Windows.xib  I then need to add a view to each (ipaduiphone) nibs in order to get a viewDidLoad to fire.  This whole Views thing has me perlexed for some reason.

Comment: That depends on which template you chose. The window-based template doesn't include any view controllers, so yes, you'd have to add one. The view-based template has a view controller and a view already set up, but you'll need to uncomment -viewDidLoad if you want to use it. But back to the question: did you hit the breakpoint on main() or not?

Comment: Yes it does break at Main.  Thanks for your help and explanations.

Answer (score 3):

Your method is just never called.

Make it

```
-(void) viewDidLoad
```

with big "L" and your chances of "breaking" will sky rocket. ;)

Comment: Sorry, my typo.  I do have it with big "L" but still doesn't dosplay.

Comment: In what class do you have the code? What's its superclass? Does the view show?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where the debugger would not stop on breakpoints in the simulator using Xcode 4C199. Turns out the simulator was just buggered and restarting it resolved the issue.

I also had the issue with XCode 3 where I had localized the name of the app to a set of Japanese characters. The debugger didn't like that. I solved that one by having english name for debug configuration and japanese name for release.